# How do I create a transparent DirectX?

Tags: directx, transparency, transparent

How do i create a transparent DirectX? I tried many times using

`direct3D9Device->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, NULL, 0.0f, 0)`

before rendering a texture, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with DirectX.

You will need:

- create layered window ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#layered), [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx))
- draw your scene to texture
- copy this texture to window contents (via [`UpdateLayeredWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

See code example [here](http://www.dhpoware.com/demos/d3dLayeredWindows.html) or on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mCrhTYQF).

<sub>Hope this helps! Happy codding.</sub>

Comment: :I tried this,But again window does't transparant. I tried in the following ways.                                                       1.Create window using "CreateWindow" ApI.                             2.After create window, then using SetWindowLong(hwnd,WS_EX_LAYERED,l); 3.Then SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd,RGB(0,0,0),0,LWA_COLORKEY|LWA_ALPHA);

Comment: No I did't check it.Because here some problem in downloading.Can u send me some code example? My created window size is 720 *120 and direct3d device size is same as window size (i.e. 720*120). But i created a Texture size is 180*120. Then I render a image in texture using sprite . My problem is " the image is displaying correctly but rest of area is always black or white. How to i change rest of area is transparant?Please help me... Please excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: @user3336737 I've copied code frome those page to pastebin.

Comment: :Hi... I have created a window as layered window then i set SetWindowLong and SetLayeredWindowAttributes with 70% transparent. Then my whole created window is transparent. I render a image from my computer ( E:\\image.jpg). In your example , image is created by us so we get hdc from that and set that hdc in RedrawLayeredWindow.But in my case i render a image form my computer then how do show render parts only in created window??? Please help me...

Comment: Draw it with DirectX as a sprite (textured quad) or just copy it to your window directly (you  don't need to bother with DirectX if you  just need one image to draw).

Comment: Hi I used SetWindowRgn for show render portion only . It is working very well if window is created manually by using CreateWindoW API. But if I use browser plugin window then it is not working, always show whole window.If u know anything about that please help me.....